# Database connection with Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, spring-boot

For the past few days i'm trying to get my Spring Boot Application online on my own server. I have installed MySql and Tomcat on there. It has worked before with a database connection as well, but with my new version it doesn't work anymore for some reason.

My application.properties is below:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbacc
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

The application does start, but when I try to add a new record to my database I'm getting the following message:

```
Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

Can someone please help me with this issue? Thank you in advance.

Part of the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String registration(Model model) {
    System.out.println("in methode registration (29)");
    model.addAttribute("userForm", new Client());

    return "registration";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") Client userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    System.out.println("in methode registration (37)");
    clientValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    clientService.save(userForm);

    securityService.autologin(userForm.getCompanyName(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

    return "redirect:/welcome";
}
```

Client model:

```
@Entity
public class Client {

private Long id;
private String companyName;

private String password;
private String passwordConfirm;

private String addressStreet;
private Long addressNumber;
private String addressNumberAdd;
private String zipCode;
private String city;

private String personToContact;
private String phoneNumber;
private String email;

//getters and setters
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>nl.insiteweb</groupId>
<artifactId>insite</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>insiteweb</name>
<description>Accountancy systeem voor Insiteweb</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cleanup</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>typography</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>zugferd</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext-licensekey</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xfaworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext-licensekey</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>itext</id>
        <name>iText Repository - releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>iText Repository</id>
        <name>iText Repository-releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>facturen/</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And the errors I get from logs/catalina.out

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:     Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2251) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:732) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:479) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
... 132 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
... 156 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please post your code which is trying to connect to the database. And pom file as well also few more mins from stack trace

Comment: I added the information, I hope you can help me.

Comment: I do have to ask..removing the app from the equation, can you login into MySQL (mysql -h localhost -u root -p password dbacc)?

Comment: As Brian mentioned check the password or host definition in mysql table. If this is not real host IP. You may miss the host permission. It must be host IP or `%` sign.

Comment: Thank you all, the issue is fixed by changing the bind address in the mysql configuration to 0.0.0.0.